# Shellscript for webpage login with xautomation

Tags: linux, bash, shell, xserver

trying to login to a webpage on my linux based infoscreen via xte (xautomation). After the browser opens it should execute this shellscript.

```
#!/bin/bash
# login-link focus with tab
times=7
for i in $times {
        xte 'key Tab'
}
xte 'key Return'
# input login credentials
xte 'str mail@provider.com'
xte 'key Tab'
xte 'str password'
# set cookie checkbox
xte 'mousemove x y'
xte 'mouseclick i'
# login
xte 'key Return'
```

It stops at the first xte command with a syntax error.
I can't figure out why. when i do the commands manually it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

change your for loop as below;

```
#!/bin/bash
# login-link focus with tab
times=7
for ((n=0;n<$times;n++))
 do
        xte 'key Tab'
 done
xte 'key Return'
# input login credentials
xte 'str mail@provider.com'
xte 'key Tab'
xte 'str password'
# set cookie checkbox
xte 'mousemove x y'
xte 'mouseclick i'
# login
xte 'key Return'
```

Comment: Thanks. Now i don't get an error and the site reloads instead of changing to the login page but the amount of Tab loops should be correct. Some progress ;)